# Syntax error on token "," , Name expected after this token

Tags: java, syntax

Can someone tell me what the syntax error is here?

```
     @Override
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(titleGraphic, (0, 0, null);
     }
```

I get the error message that I put in the subject line for the comma after "titleGraphic,".  I think I'm missing another ")" after the "null" but the comma is giving me trouble.  This is what I get for trying something out of a book.

Comment: It looks like you've got an extra `(`, not a missing one.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra paren:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(titleGraphic, (0, 0, null);
                                ^
```

Comment: Thanks!  It's the simple things in life.

Comment: A code editor such as Notepad++ (or any editor with color coding and bracket matching) would have fixed your problem in seconds.